Cisco Packet tracer 8..2..2 not combatible with ubuntu 24.04
Unable to download Cisco Packet tracer 8.2.2. The latest version as not compatible with Ubuntu 24.04 need this file. I believe can't find one that works libgl1-mesa-gl. This is the message that comes up when I try to install packet tracer.
(Reading database ... 218755 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack CiscoPacketTracer.deb ...
Unpacking packettracer (8.2.2) over (8.2.2) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: No theme index file.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on libgl1-mesa-glx; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.4-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer


This is not an Ubuntu issue, but a Cisco issue. You could try first installing the dependencies of libgl1-mesa-glx with:
sudo apt install libgl1 libglx-mesa0

And then you could download the package libgl1-mesa-glx for Ubuntu 22.04 and install it manually:
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_22.0.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libgl1-mesa-glx_22.0.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

If this does not work, contact Cisco and persuade them to release a version of Packet Tracer 8.2.2 that's compatible with the packages for Ubuntu 24.04.
